# Broken packages error while installing zookeeper-server

Tags: apt, hadoop

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty) and was trying to install Cloudera Hadoop with Yarn by following [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-0-0/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_cdh5_install.html) tutorial.

Under the options I choose `To add the CDH 5 repository:` and customized url for `trusty` OS. Then I installed Zookeeper but while installing Zookeeper-Server it is giving me following error:

```
$    sudo apt-get install zookeeper-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zookeeper-server : Depends: zookeeper (= 3.4.5+cdh5.3.2+83-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.17~trusty-cdh5.3.2) but 3.4.5+dfsg-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

File: /etc/apt/sources.list

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

And also:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh trusty-cdh5 contrib
deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh trusty-cdh5 contrib

deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./
deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
```

How to manage this broken packages problem and install zookeeper successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On reading this [blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/guidelines-for-installing-cdh-packages-on-unsupported-operating-systems/), I came to know this was not issue more of broken packages.
 To resolve this broken package error:

1. Uninstall previous Zookeeper:

   $ sudo apt-get remove zookeeper

   $ sudo apt-get purge zookeeper
2. Fresh install Zookeeper

   $ sudo apt-get install zookeeper
3. Install Zookeeper Server

   $ sudo apt-get install zookeeper-server