# Need help to fix broken packages while installing shutter

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

A brief background:
Recently, I had deleted libnl-3-200 library by mistake.. and was able to fix the issue as described in [Deleted libnl-3-200 by mistake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069629/deleted-libnl-3-200-by-mistake)

After the network was working, I did sudo apt-get autoremove and sudo apt-get autoclean. I noticed that ubuntu is trying to remove important packages, so I stopped the process by pressing Ctrl + C.

I have two desktops : fvwm and gnome(ubuntu-default).
After I restarted my system, the gnome desktop did not show up in the login screen. Also, I use wicd network manager to connect to internet.

I tried to follow this link [Broken packages error while installing zookeeper-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593175/broken-packages-error-while-installing-zookeeper-server)
but didn't helped me.

When I do `sudo apt-get install shutter`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shutter : Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-vfs-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-unique-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Next, I tried to run `sudo apt-get purge shutter`.
Log is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apturl apturl-common epiphany-browser-data gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  gnome-session-common guile-2.0-libs libatk1.0-0:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavahi-gobject0
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-common
  libcairo2:i386 libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
  libcommon-sense-perl libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl
  libdata-random-perl libdatrie1:i386 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libexiv2-14
  libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreerdp-cache1.1
  libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0
  libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1
  libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-primitives1.1
  libfreerdp-utils1.1 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd-perl
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgexiv2-2 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnome2-canvas-perl libgnome2-gconf-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl
  libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-common libgnutls30:i386
  libgoo-canvas-perl libgoocanvas-common libgoocanvas3 libgraphite2-3:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtk2-appindicator-perl libgtk2-imageview-perl
  libgtkimageview0 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhttp-server-simple-perl libidn11:i386 libimage-magick-perl
  libimage-magick-q16-perl libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
  libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libmouse-perl libnet-dropbox-api-perl
  libnet-oauth-perl libnettle6:i386 liborbit-2-0 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring
  libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpath-class-perl libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng12-0:i386
  libproc-processtable-perl libproc-simple-perl libraw15
  libsort-naturally-perl libssh-4 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386
  libthai0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtypes-serialiser-perl libvncclient1
  libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1
  libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1
  libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1
  libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1
  libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1
  libwnck-common libwnck22 libwww-mechanize-perl libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-128-generic oneconf-common p11-kit p11-kit-modules
  perlmagick planner-data planner-doc python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-attr python-blinker python-cups
  python-debian python-debtagshw python-defer python-dirspec python-httplib2
  python-jwt python-oauthlib python-oneconf python-pam
  python-piston-mini-client python-pyasn1-modules python-serial
  python-service-identity python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core
  python-twisted-web python-xapian python-zope.interface python3-oneconf
  python3-piston-mini-client remmina-common scrollkeeper shotwell-common
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  shutter*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 349811 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing shutter (0.93.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Purging configuration files for shutter (0.93.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

---

Please help me to correct this issue?

Comment: just a hint that might not relate to your issue: `ctrl-z` does not stop but suspend (=pause) the process. `ctrl-c` stops the process.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f` and tell us the output.

Comment: Thanks RoVo for reply, the log is same as 2nd log shown above.

Comment: Please read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa/142808) and see if it may help you.

Comment: I am scared to run sudo apt-get clean, as it might delete important packages too. Does apt ensure to not delete important packages?

Comment: I'd be afraid too with that list ;-)

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get clean and autoclean.. and later part till 

sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade.. but no luck :-(

Comment: What repositories are you using ?ppa or other 3rd party repos? Did you run `sudo apt update`? What version of ubuntu?

Comment: My ubuntu version is " 16.04.5 LTS ". Yes, sudo apt-get update is running fine with no errors. Please check the sources.list at https://pastebin.com/54DcQ27j

Comment: What are those lucid ppa ?

Comment: It is for mario game.

Comment: After running sudo apt-get upgrade,  I am getting this log https://pastebin.com/gsFeDMNq Please help!

Comment: Running sudo apt-get -f install gives: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.

Comment: I tried to run the commands mentioned in this link: http://sourcedigit.com/21301-fix-broken-packages-ubuntu-terminal-list-broken-packages-ubuntu/  ... Getting this log with sudo apt-get install shutter  https://pastebin.com/71ZNRgfs

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and getting this log: https://pastebin.com/yAyHdqZU .. Is it okay to press Y? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my sources.list file as given here [Shutter is not getting installed in Ubuntu 16.04 due to unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894639/shutter-is-not-getting-installed-in-ubuntu-16-04-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

Then,I ran sudo apt-get update , sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

And was able to install shutter without facing any broken package issue.

Though, the solution worked after lot of hit and trial ... what effects my ubuntu
system will have after upgrading source list of repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

`shutter` is part of the GNOME suite, which is installed through a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages), so if you remove it, *apt* also has to remove the metapackage as its dependencies are no longer fulfilled. This causes all packages that were installed only as dependencies of the metapackage to be removed as well.

During the initial installation, the Ubuntu system will just tell *apt* to install a bunch of metapackages, such as `ubuntu-minimal`, `ubuntu-standard` and `gnome-desktop-environment`, and these packages contain the actual list of applications to install. That way, there is no need to adjust the installer when a package is added to or removed from the standard installation, and upgrades will also adapt to the new list.

This makes upgrades to new Ubuntu releases a lot more robust, for example the decision to replace *sysvinit* by *systemd* could be communicated through a simple change in the `ubuntu-minimal` package, and all standard Ubuntu installations picked up on that and made the transition.

If you want to manually maintain the list of packages you want to have installed, I suggest you install [`aptitude`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptitudeSurvivalGuide), which lets you review and modify the list of changes before performing them. Note that upgrades might need a bit more handholding then.

Comment: I ran sudo aptitude install shutter, and got this log https://pastebin.com/JmipVrGN

Comment: After pressing 'Y': I get a message to delete a list of packages with a total size of 92.8 MB.

Comment: @RISHABHJAIN, you can use the 'e' key there to get into a text UI, or you can start aptitude without any arguments to start in the UI.

Comment: Yes, i can see the text UI window. May you suggest what to do there?

Comment: @RISHABHJAIN, the wiki page I linked in the answer gives a quick overview.

Comment: Hello Simon, I tried to run the commands mentioned in this link: http://sourcedigit.com/21301-fix-broken-packages-ubuntu-terminal-list-broken-packages-ubuntu/… ... Getting this log with sudo apt-get install shutter https://pastebin.com/71ZNRgfs

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and getting this log: https://pastebin.com/yAyHdqZU .. Is it okay to press Y?

Comment: I pressed yes, the ran sudo apt-get autoremove! Here is the log https://pastebin.com/5qiUHwHN